# Highlight matplotlib points that go over or under a threshold in colors based on the amount the boundaries are crossed

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, anaconda

I have a graph that looks like this:

[image]

And the code I'm running to get this graph (one of a sequence of 8 graphs) is below:

```
date_list =  list(df_testing_set['date'].unique())

random_date_list = list(np.random.choice(date_list,8))

df_new = df_testing_set[df_testing_set['date'].isin(random_date_list)]

for date1 in random_date_list:
df_new = df_testing_set[df_testing_set['date'] == date1]
title = date1

if df_new.iloc[0]['day'] in ['Saturday', 'Sunday']:
    df_shader = df_result_weekend.copy()
    title += " - Weekend"
else:
    df_shader = df_result_weekday.copy()
    title += " - Weekday"

y = df_new[row_index].tolist()
x = range(0, len(y))
x_axis = buckets
y_axis = df_shader.loc[df_shader.index.isin([row_index]) & df_shader['Bucket'].between(1, 144), data_field].tolist()
del y_axis[-1]


plt.title(title)
plt.xlabel("Time of Day (10m Intervals)")
plt.ylabel(data_field + " values for " + row_index)

standevs = df_shader.loc[df_shader.index.isin([row_index]) & df_shader['Bucket'].between(1, 144), 'StanDev'].tolist()
del standevs[-1]
lower_bound = np.array(y_axis) - np.array(standevs)
upper_bound = np.array(y_axis) + np.array(standevs)

plt.fill_between(x_axis, lower_bound, upper_bound, facecolor='lightblue')

#highlighting anomalies
#   if (y > upper_bound | y < lower_bound):
#       plt.plot(x,y, 'rx')
#   else:
#       plt.plot(x, y)



plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

del df_shader, title, date1, df_new
```

I'm trying to create a condition (like the commented if statement) such that when the plotted coordinates go above the threshold `upper_bound` or below `lower_bound`, the points are marked with an 'x' in different colors. I want to in the end have it such that if a point exceeds the threshold by 1 standard deviation, it will be marked in orange, and if it exceeds by 2 or more standard deviations, it will be marked in red. I have all the standard deviations in the data frame `df_shader` under the column `StanDev`. Whenever I try to run some variation of the if-block, I get variable errors and name errors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use boolean masks to select points that fulfill certain conditions,
and plot them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

std = 0.1
N = 100

x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
expected_y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)
y = expected_y + np.random.normal(0, std, N)

dist = np.abs(y - expected_y) / std

mask1 = (1 < dist) & (dist <= 2)
mask2 = dist > 2

plt.fill_between(x, expected_y - 0.1, expected_y + 0.1, alpha=0.1)
plt.fill_between(x, expected_y - 0.2, expected_y + 0.2, alpha=0.1)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x[mask1], y[mask1], 'x')
plt.plot(x[mask2], y[mask2], 'x')


plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('mp_points.png', dpi=300)
```

Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

Use [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to identify these points and plot them separately:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(20)

b = x > 0.7

print(b)
print(x[b])
```

Comment: I see, could you explain a little how I could use them in conjunction with the standard deviations to create the tiers based on which colors are assigned?

Comment: Still need help? Or is @MaxNoe's answer clear enough?

Comment: I would actually love some more direction, I've kind of been thrown into this without knowing a whole lot and its a lot to take in. His answer is fantastically laid out, but I'm still quite unsure as to how to incorporate it directly into my code

Comment: On boolean indexing or plotting and numpy in general? Have you read the link on boolean indexing I posted in my answer? Boolean indexing let's you pick only those numbers in an array that match a stated condition, e.g. for `x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` you can pick the numbers greater or equal than 3 like `x >= 3`. The result is `y = np.array([False. False, True, True, True])`. Afterwards you can apply y to x like `x[y]` to get the result `np.array([3,4,5])`. Takes a bit to get used to, but is very useful.

Comment: I understand the boolean indexing! That seems pretty straightforward. It how to use it with the `x_axis` and `y_axis` from my code without changing the data to the point where I cannot refer to the data frame the same way afterwards that goes over my head. Things list the standard deviation also change by each coordinate, so I'm not sure how to use what has been given into a suitable solution. I'm sorry if the answer is plain and I just seem ignorant, but it hasn't hit me yet.

Comment: As long as you don't overwrite your original array it stays unchanged. The boolean indexing is only temporary, in numpy terms it is called a *view* on the original array. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view

Comment: I see. Alright, I'll let it take me where it takes me and learn more along the way! Thank you :)

Comment: A good starting point is to separate your script like MaxNoe did. In the first section just preprocess the data, convert it, create the standard deviation, etc. Then use a section where only the plotting is done.