# Mark specific points on graph with x matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I have a matplotlib graph like so:

[image]

I'm trying to mark plots that go outside the green range (defined by a `lower_bound` and an `upper_bound`) with a red 'x'.

Below is my code with the loop I was originally writing to create the x's commented out:

```
y = df_new[row_index].tolist()
x = range(0, len(y))
x_axis = buckets
y_axis = df_shader.loc[df_shader.index.isin([row_index]) & df_shader['Bucket'].between(1, 144), data_field].tolist()
minus = df_shader.loc[df_shader.index.isin([row_index]) & df_shader['Bucket'].between(1, 144), 'Lower'].tolist()
plus = df_shader.loc[df_shader.index.isin([row_index]) & df_shader['Bucket'].between(1, 144), 'Upper'].tolist()
del y_axis[-1], minus[-2], plus[-2]


plt.title(title)
plt.xlabel("Time of Day (10m Intervals)")
plt.ylabel(data_field + " values for " + row_index)

standevs = df_shader.loc[df_shader.index.isin([row_index]) & df_shader['Bucket'].between(1, 144), 'StanDev'].tolist()
del standevs[-1]
lower_bound = np.array(y_axis) - np.array(standevs)
upper_bound = np.array(y_axis) + np.array(standevs)
minus = np.array(minus)
min2 = minus - np.array(standevs)
plus = np.array(plus)
pl2 = plus + np.array(standevs)

meh = max(upper_bound.tolist())
moh = min(lower_bound.tolist())

plt.axhline(y=meh, color='red')
plt.axhline(y=moh, color='red') #Intercepts
plt.fill_between(x_axis, upper_bound, pl2, color='orange')
plt.fill_between(x_axis, lower_bound, upper_bound, color='lightgreen')
plt.fill_between(x_axis, min2, lower_bound, color='orange')

#   for right, up in x, y:
#       if up > upper_bound:
#           plt.plot(right,up,'rx')
#       if up < lower_bound:
#           plt.plot(right, up, 'rx')
#       else:
#           plt.plot(right, up)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

How do I get the x's to print out?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45208912/4124317) already provides a [mcve] of your issue. Why don't you use it here? Also the solution to this question seems to be pretty similar to the answer provided, just that you need a different mask. What prevents you from implementing it, where is the problem?

Comment: Here you need `mask3 = y > meh; plt.plot(x[mask3], y[mask3], 'x')`; everything else is the same as in the [duplicate quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208226/highlight-matplotlib-points-that-go-over-or-under-a-threshold-in-colors-based-on).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest when I try what you just posted, the only point that ends up marked with the 'x' is at the front of the graph. I know for a fact that there are other points that should be marked as well, but not how to get them all

Comment: That might be; but nobody can reproduce this, so you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue.